# Bytes32 and Data Payload question

Tags: remix, bytes32

Hello Solidity Expert,

I am working on Ethernaut challenge 8 called Vault: [Ethernaut](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/)  See the contract code at the end of this post.

I feel I solved the challenge but for some reason I cannot open the vault.

Here are the steps I have taken.

1. I found the contract on Rinkeby and extracted the Bytes32 component from the constructor.  Contract 0x5F694fcf2767ff28c0907eEAF6b705E8456a3665

[image]

2. I entered the Bytes32 component into the parameter of the unlock function but the vault does not unlock?

[image]

I am not certain what I did wrong here. In my mind the Vault should open.  Any hints or insights are welcome.

Thank you.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Vault {
  bool public locked;
  bytes32 private password;

  constructor(bytes32 _password) public {
    locked = true;
    password = _password;
  }

  function unlock(bytes32 _password) public {
    if (password == _password) {
      locked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I used web3.eth.getStorageAt("0x5F694fcf2767ff28c0907eEAF6b705E8456a3665", 1, console.log) to get access to password and the result was 

0x412076657279207374726f6e67207365637265742070617373776f7264203a29

which unlocked the Vault but I am not sure why this differs from the data in the constructor as noted on Rinkeby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the transaction highlighted is to a 'factory' contract that deploys the vault. It isn't a direct call to the constructor.

To determine the constructor parameter you can to examine the [internal transaction](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xa9734212df5a0085f7cfbdd47cc966d248d60006c5098e847edf0475ff87ba4d&type=gethtrace2) that creates the contract.

At CREATE's input end the same parameter you found appears

> 412076657279207374726f6e67207365637265742070617373776f7264203a29